# How to authenticate mac user to windows active directory in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, active-directory

This requirement is about authenticating the mac users in windows active directory.I am new to the objective-c.I was able to find the user name and password in objective-c, but authentication part is remaining.
Can anyone guide me on this , since I searched a lot but didn't able to find it.Please note that this requirement is very specific for mac machines connected to the windows active directory.
Please guide me on this.
Thanks.

Comment: have you looked into NSURLAuthenticationChallenge ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/Open_Directory/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code for this? I searched on this but there is some confusion in it.I am still not clear on how to apply this for windows active directory. Please let me know if any other thing I need to try for it.

Comment: If you know any specific API or function which can be used in coding, then please share that also.Thanks.

Comment: There is one more way to authenticate the user.I tried running the ODBC commands for active directory and it worked.Please add your thoughts on it if you know some other way of doing it.Thanks,Tausif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one more way to authenticate the user.I tried running the ODBC commands for active directory and it worked.Please add your thoughts on it if you know some other way of doing it.Thanks,Tausif.